# errors when using case in where clause

Tags: sql

I have used following code.. but it have some erors...pls help me

```
    SELECT VoucherTypes.types, 
           VoucherHead.VoucherNo, 
           VoucherHead.VoucherDate, 
           SUM(VoucherDetail.Debit) AS debit, 
           SUM(VoucherDetail.Credit) AS credit,
           VoucherHead.VoucherStatus
    FROM  VoucherHead 
          INNER JOIN VoucherTypes 
          ON VoucherHead.VoucherType = VoucherTypes.vtypeid 
          INNER JOIN VoucherDetail 
          ON VoucherHead.VoucherID = VoucherDetail.VoucherID
    WHERE(VoucherHead.VoucherDate &gt;= @fromdate) 
    AND (VoucherHead.VoucherDate &lt;= @todate) 
    AND (VoucherTypes.types = @vtype) 
    AND (VoucherHead.Branchno = @branchid)
    and case(VoucherHead.VoucherStatus)
         when @val=1 then 
              VoucherHead.VoucherStatus='true' 
         when @val=2 then 
              VoucherHead.VoucherStatus=false 
         when @val=0 then 
              VoucherHead.VoucherStatus=true or 
              VoucherHead.VoucherStatus=false or 
              VoucherHead.VoucherStatus is null
 GROUP BY VoucherTypes.types, 
          VoucherHead.VoucherNo, 
          VoucherHead.VoucherDate, 
          VoucherHead.VoucherStatus
```

Comment: Add the error message.

Comment: Which dbms? (Some non ANSI SQL there...)

Comment: case when cond1 then ... when cond2 then .... end

Comment: The errors are   Error in WHERE clause near '='.
Error in WHERE clause near 'GROUP'.
Error in WHERE clause near ','.
Unable to parse query text.

Comment: You don't END the CASE...

Answer (score 2):

Try this, might work for you. Itis tough to understand your Requirement through your Question.

```
   SELECT VoucherTypes.types, 
           VoucherHead.VoucherNo, 
           VoucherHead.VoucherDate, 
           SUM(VoucherDetail.Debit) AS debit, 
           SUM(VoucherDetail.Credit) AS credit,
           VoucherHead.VoucherStatus    
    FROM  VoucherHead 
    INNER JOIN VoucherTypes ON VoucherHead.VoucherType = VoucherTypes.vtypeid 
    INNER JOIN VoucherDetail ON VoucherHead.VoucherID = VoucherDetail.VoucherID
    WHERE (VoucherHead.VoucherDate &gt;= @fromdate) 
      AND (VoucherHead.VoucherDate &lt;= @todate) 
      AND (VoucherTypes.types = @vtype) 
      AND (VoucherHead.Branchno = @branchid)
      AND (@val=0 OR VH.VoucherStatus = case when @val=1 then 'true' 
          when @val=2 then 'false' END)
    GROUP BY VoucherTypes.types, VoucherHead.VoucherNo, VoucherHead.VoucherDate, VoucherHead.VoucherStatus
```

Comment: sory for discribing my question...here the variable @val can take values 1, 2, 3. .if @val=1 i want to show the rows in which voucherstatus='true' or if  @val=2 i want to show the rows in which voucherstatus='false'  or  @val=3 i want to show the rows in which voucherstatus='true' or false or null. (ie if @val=3 it retrive all rows )

Comment: @IP_PC5 I have modified my answer. try this.
Surely work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The regular `CASE` syntax is (somewhat simplified):

```
case when x = y then value-expression1
     when z = q then value-expression2
     etc...
   [ else value-expressionx ]
end
```

The `else`-clause is optional. All return value-expressions must have compatible data-types.

Answer (score 1):

You should write a query as:

```
SELECT VT.[types], 
       VH.VoucherNo, 
       VH.VoucherDate,
       SUM(VD.Debit) AS debit,
       SUM(VD.Credit) AS credit,
       VH.VoucherStatus
    FROM  VoucherHead VH 
    INNER JOIN VoucherTypes VT ON VH.VoucherType = VT.vtypeid
    INNER JOIN VoucherDetail VD ON VH.VoucherID = VD.VoucherID
    WHERE (VH.VoucherDate >= @fromdate) 
    AND (VH.VoucherDate <= @todate) 
    AND (VT.[types] = @vtype) 
    AND (VH.Branchno = @branchid)
    and 1 = ( CASE 
              when @val=1 AND  VH.VoucherStatus='true' THEN 1
              when @val=2 AND  VH.VoucherStatus='false' THEN 1
              --when @val= 0 AND  (VH.VoucherStatus='true' or
              --VH.VoucherStatus='false' or VH.VoucherStatus is NULL)
              --THEN 1
              when @val=3 THEN 1  ELSE 0 END )
    GROUP BY VT.[types], VH.VoucherNo, VH.VoucherDate, VH.VoucherStatus
```

Comment: i got an error like this.    error message:parameter 7:(.........).The clr type does not exist or you dont have permission to access it.

Comment: just add `  and 1 = ( CASE 
              when @val=1 AND  VH.VoucherStatus='true' THEN 1
              when @val=2 AND  VH.VoucherStatus='false' THEN 1
              --when @val= 0 AND  (VH.VoucherStatus='true' or
              --VH.VoucherStatus='false' or VH.VoucherStatus is NULL)
              --THEN 1
              ELSE 1 END )` in your original query ..

Comment: i run this query in sql management studio..it works... when @val=1 it retrieve rows with value 1 and null. When @val=2  shows rows with value 1 and null. and same for @val=3..

Comment: But what i want is if @val=1 i want to show the rows in which voucherstatus='true'  only or if  @val=2 i want to show the rows in which voucherstatus='false' only or  @val=3 i want to show the rows in which voucherstatus='true' or false or null. (ie if @val=3 it retrive all rows )...pls help me.....i want to get answer in anyway, using case is not neccarly...